need kotlin function code in android studio to create a screenshot of the android desktop
I can’t write a function in Android Studio using Kotlin that takes a snapshot of the Android desktop
fun takeViewScreenshot(view: View) {
    Toast.makeText(view.context, "Скриншот сохранен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width, view.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    view.draw(canvas)
    saveBitmap(bitmap)
}

takes a screenshot of only the current activity, but not the Android desktop
